# Is it possible to prevent a graphic raycaster blocking 2D rays in different layers, from a different camera?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I have a graphic raycaster attached to a canvas, with the blocking layer set to exclude all layers except "UI":

`_graphicRaycaster.blockingMask = LayerMask.GetMask("UI");`

The canvas is set to "Screen Space - Camera", and there is a dedicated UICam also set to the UI layer with a physics2D raycaster also with the mask set to "UI". This is because I have an elaborate UI that relies on Image objects and physics2D colliders to detect input.

I also have a physics2D raycaster attached to the main camera, for interacting with the actual game objects. I would like to still receive click events on gameobjects when the UI is active.

This raycaster has the event mask set to the gameObjects layer, and all interactive objects are in that layer. Those events are detected when the canvas is disabled.

I am implementing `IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler` and so forth in the various interactive ui elements and game objects. I am not firing rays manually.

However, when avtive, the graphic raycaster seems to block all events from the main camera's raycaster, irrespective of the mask settings on any of the objects.

Is it possible prevent it from doing this?

Comment: Did you solve this?  I'm seeing the same thing. Doing a:
            Debug.Log("Raycaster: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.module.gameObject.name);
shows the wrong Raycaster being used.

Comment: no, I ended up refactoring to some others approach but I didn't solve this exact issue